# How to Send Email from custom html form in wordpress?

Tags: php, html, wordpress, smtp

I have created a custom html form and on submitting form i want to send a email to the owner using my mail.php file but when i am submmiting my form i get this

> This page isn’t working
>
> Yoursite.com is currently unable to handle
>
> this request. HTTP ERROR 500

Here is my form

```
<form action="mail.php">
    <label for="fname">Full Name</label>
    <input type="text" id="fname" name="name" placeholder="Your name..">

    <label for="email">Email</label>
    <input type="email" id="email" name="email" placeholder="Your email..">
   <label for="contact">Contact number</label>
    <input type="tel" id="contact" name="phone" placeholder="Your contact number..">
     <label for="subject">Description</label>
    <textarea id="subject" name="msg" placeholder="Tell us your requirements.." style="height:100px"> 
    </textarea>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
  </form>
```

and here is my mail.php file

```
<?php
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\Exception;
require 'vendor/autoload.php';
$mail = new PHPMailer(true);                              // Passing `true` enables exceptions
try {
    $name    = $_POST["name"];
    $email   = $_POST["email"];
    $phone   = $_POST["phone"];
    $message = $_POST["msg"];
    //Server settings
    $mail->SMTPDebug = 2;                                 // Enable verbose debug output
    $mail->isSMTP();                                      // Set mailer to use SMTP
    $mail->Host = '';  // Specify main and backup SMTP servers
    $mail->SMTPAuth = true;                               // Enable SMTP authentication

    $mail->Username = '';                 // SMTP username
    //$mail->Password = '';                           // SMTP password
    $mail->Password = '';                           // SMTP password
    $mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';                            // Enable TLS encryption, `ssl` also accepted
    $mail->Port = 587;                                    // TCP port to connect to

    //Recipients
    $mail->setFrom('owner@gmail.com', 'Mailer');

    $mail->addAddress('nitin@gmail.com');               // Name is optional
    $mail->addReplyTo('info@example.com', 'Information');

    $mail->isHTML(true);                                  // Set email format to HTML
    $mail->Subject = 'Request Enquiry';
    $mail->Body    = "             <html>     <body> <center>         <table border='0' align='center'>     <tr> <td> <b><span style='color:#005BAC;font-family:arial; font-size:20px;'>4 Way Technologies</span> </td> </tr>             </table> <table>     <tr> <td>Name : </td>             <td>$name</td>         </tr>         <tr> <td>Email : </td>         <td>$email</td>                 </tr>     <tr> <td>Phone : </td>             <td>$phone</td>             </tr>     <tr> <td>Message : </td> <td>$message</td>             </tr><tr> <td>URL : </td> <td>$url</td>             </tr>         </table>         </center>     </body>     </html>";
    //$mail->AltBody = 'This is the body in plain text for non-HTML mail clients';

    $mail->send();
    // header('Location:thankyou.php');
} catch (Exception $e) {
   // 'Message could not be sent. Mailer Error: ', $mail->ErrorInfo;
}
```

**I have inserted mail.php on Wordpress/htdocs folder**

Comment: You can use `wp_mail` function to send email using custom html form.

Answer (score 1):

Hey Please insert your mail file inside wordpress like wordpress/mail.php
and then in form action use `**action="<?php echo home_url(); ?>/mail.php"**`

**You can also test http://yoursite.com/mail.php should work**

Comment: when i am creating file on wordpress  folder it shows permission denined so if i do action="<?php echo home_url();" ?>/htdocs/mail.php" will it work  ??

Comment: This will not work as your domain is pointed to word press directory. You need to put mail file inside word-press directory.

Comment: There is one more create page template mail.php inside theme folder and then create page send-email and assign mail.php template to this page.

Comment: so now i am trying to change wordpress folder permission from 755 to 777 but it is still showing me access denied so is there any way i can change directory permission

Comment: There is one more create page template mail.php inside theme folder and then create page send-email and assign mail.php template to this page. In action then pass action ="pageurl" like yoursite.com/send-email

Comment: Hey  i am able to create mail.php on wordpress directory but now on submitting form am rdirecting to my 404 page not found and getting this url   https://yoursite.com/%3C?name=Nitin+tiwari&email=nitin%40gmail.com&phone=91464444486&msg=xcsdvfdghfjg&captchaenable=captchaenable&g-recaptcha-response=03AOLTBLTtkwO2ILz8IdLXeDuZFg1uurD698772VfX3yFylX9dSL4TifFaJ_27TXb6Cosn9xmHMoNtmymHuqhNp8zU5uGxVBBLFxdv9NcUws7ntG61hknBv0SdvZat13mzfiG0c0LaH9O7_2L67gnR_mt0jaxZTvcB1l8gB4IMxzwUfwFft9XuSYU2c6mY-BgsV3dt49ScngFSMuTRmnqvDffYTWkKMKtUzPmqUPwyym6G0rkf2fJrphyVeh561jyj4R672xSw9hFv821BNQgbdee

Comment: <form action="<?php echo home_url(); ?>/mail.php"  method="POST"> please use this code.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/205437/discussion-between-naval-and-nitin-tiwari).

Answer (score 0):

You can use :

```
<?php bloginfo('stylesheet_directory'); ?>/mail.php
```